# KeyMap - 3D ViewPort Pan : Shift + Mouse Move only (Remove Middle Mouse Button)

Tags: keymap

Is there a way to have the 3D Viewport PAN feature by removing the <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> *Press* and keep only the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Move</kbd> key map?

I have tried by unchecking the following key mapping :
*Edit > Preferences > KeyMap > 3DView > 3DView Global > Pan View* <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse</kbd>

and kept :

*Edit > Preferences > KeyMap > 3DView > 3DView Global > Pan View* <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse/TrackPad Pan</kbd>

Blender Version : v3.3.14 on Windows 10

I'm trying to have the same behavior as FreeCAD with the TouchPad navigation style.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can create 3 keymap entries all for Pan View tied to Shift Left Mouse, Shift Middle Mouse, and Shift Right Mouse. Just don't forget to move Shift Right Mouse for Move 3D Cursor, and Shift Left Mouse for Select (Toggle)

[image]

Comment: I would like only "press" on the "shift" key + a mouse "move" without any mouse click (no left click, no middle click and no right click).

Comment: If you mean holding down the Shift key, and waving the mouse left and right, then sadly that's impossible in Blender.